# R - Compare and delete rows with identical column value in data frame while keeping one of them

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame which consists of several rows with identical values in the column “name” but different values in the column “distance”. I would like to delete all rows with identical entries in “name” save for the one with the smallest distance. Is there an easier way than comparing all the rows with each other and check if their “name” entry is identical before comparing their “distance” value? The real data frame is about 14000 rows x 14 columns.
I've looked for an answer but haven't found anything yet, so I’d be very thankful for any help!

This would be the original data frame:

```
     name      distance number
[1,] "apple"   "2.5"    "4"   
[2,] "banana"  "3"      "6"   
[3,] "apple"   "1"      "2"   
[4,] "satsuma" "4"      "8"   
[5,] "satsuma" "7.5"    "1"   
[6,] "melon"   "3"      "3"   
[7,] "satsuma" "1"      "6"
```

This is what I'd like to get (not necessarily in this order):

```
     name      distance number
[1,] "banana"  "3"      "6"   
[2,] "apple"   "1"      "2"   
[3,] "melon"   "3"      "3"   
[4,] "satsuma" "1"      "6"
```

Comment: That's not a data.frame, rather it's a matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, sort the data.frame by `name` and `distance`, then mark rows to keep as the first ones for each name:

```
sorted <- dat[order(dat$name, dat$distance), ]

keep <- c(TRUE, head(sorted$name,-1) != tail(sorted$name,-1))
```

The result is

```
sorted[keep, ]
```

Comment: Yeah this likely the fastest approach. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aggregate` and `merge` like below

```
DF <- read.table(text='name      distance number
apple   2.5    4   
banana  3      6   
apple   1      2   
satsuma 4      8   
satsuma 7.5    1   
melon   3      3   
satsuma 1      6', header=TRUE)

merge(DF, aggregate(distance ~ name, data = DF, min))
##      name distance number
## 1   apple        1      2
## 2  banana        3      6
## 3   melon        3      3
## 4 satsuma        1      6
```

Comment: Nice approach.  Never would have thought of that. +1

Answer (score 1):

A couple of pointers to start:

Make your data as easy for others to read as possible.  `dput(head(your_data))` is a nice way to do that.  And two your data is in a matrix rather than a dataframe so you have the least restrictive data type being character, so all your data is a character.  I think storing it as a data.frame is better here because you have mixed data types.  So right off the bat I read your data in as a dataframe and made sure the distance column was numeric.

```
dat <- read.table(text='
name      distance number
"apple"   "2.5"    "4"   
"banana"  "3"      "6"   
"apple"   "1"      "2"   
"satsuma" "4"      "8"   
"satsuma" "7.5"    "1"   
"melon"   "3"      "3"   
"satsuma" "1"      "6"', header=T)  

dat$distance <- as.numeric(dat$distance)


#split by grouping variable
splitdat <- split(dat, dat$name)

#find the minimum distance and index that 
out <- lapply(splitdat, function(x) {
    x[which.min(x$distance), ]
})

#put it all back together as a data frame
data.frame(do.call(rbind, out), row.names=NULL)
```

This is one of many approaches.

Comment: Useful newb-advice. The `lapply(split(..,..))` paradigm is very similar to the `by` I used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the advice! This was my first question here and I tried to make it as generic as possible (my real data is a data frame and not a matrix).

Answer (score 1):

I see @geektrader's aggregate-merge approach, but wonder if the merge might be might be CPU and memory intensive:

```
do.call(rbind, by( DF, DF['name'], function(d) d[which.min(d$distance), ] ) )
           name distance number
apple     apple        1      2
banana   banana        3      6
melon     melon        3      3
satsuma satsuma        1      6
```